# Android: I have two threads...how do I pass data between them?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm building a game in Android, and I have two threads. One for my data, and one for my UI. Up to this point, it's been fairly straightforward, as the UI thread pulls data that updates from the main thread without a problem. The issue I'm running into, is that my UI thread pauses certain parts of the game(a countdown timer) while it runs a certain animation, and I need a way to start that countdown timer again in the data thread, once the animation has ended. I have some solutions I've been working up, but it all seems so convoluted.

Is there something like a listener or something evens simpler where I can indicate to my data thread that a specific animation has ended in my UI thread? I just can't seem to get it to work the way I want.

Here's a pseudo code version of what I'm doing:

```
Main
{
    gamethread();
    UIthread:



   while(gameIsRunning)
   {
       UIthread.draw();

      if(gamethread.startAnimationButtonIsPressed)
      {
        UIthread.startAnimation;
      }

   }


}
```

Basically, in this pseudo code example, I'd need a way to indicate to the gamethread to unpress the startanimation button, or toggle that boolean or whatever.

Comment: I think this question is way too vague to be answerable.  There's dozens of ways to pass data between threads, the "correct" way depends on frequency of writes and reads by each thread, how recent each thread needs the data to be, etc.  We don't know enough about the way your app works to answer this.  Although I will say in general if you have a UI thread and a logic thread, the logic thread should know everything about when to restart itself, it shouldn't be reliant on the UI thread telling it.  Sounds like you haven't separated the UI from the logic enough.

Comment: That's sort of the kind of answer I'm looking for. Less specifics, more general practice. Appreciate the response.